# Delayed_job : NoMethodError: undefined method `my_method_without_delay'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

Using rails 2.3.11 and delayed_job 2.0.4 as a gem I get an error when using `handle_asynchronously` :

In my ActionMailer model, I delcared my_method and added ' handle_asynchronously :my_method' right after the declaration :

```
class MailSender < ActionMailer::Base
    def my_method
        ...
    end
    handle_asynchronously :my_method
end
```

When calling `MailSender.deliver_my_method` the task is correctly added to the queue. But when trying to process it, it fails with the error message :

```
undefined method `rappel_email_without_delay' for #<YAML::Object:0x1034b85f8>
```

Delaying with `MailSender.delay.deliver_my_method` is working and the task correctly processed - But i'd rather use `handle_asynchronously` un my model to ensure mail are always sent in the background...

Answer (score 6):

You need to restart the worker processes using

> rake jobs:work

Comment: that should not be required, as delayed_job is supposed to run by itself. how to investigate on this one ?

Answer (score 5):

Also had this problem in 3.2.3.

Fixed it by restarting the DJ process after every code change.

Comment: Yeap, this fixes it.  Makes working with the Rails console a bit of a pain though.

Answer (score 0):

You can still declare using the handle_asynchronously macro, but the syntax for calling delayed jobs with ActionMailer is a bit different.

```
# without delayed_job
MailSender.my_method.deliver

# with delayed_job
MailSerder.delay.my_method
```

This was pulled from an older version of the README, but it's not in the current one, so maybe a newer version of delayed jobs worked around this nuance.

Comment: This looks like Rails 3 mailer - I'm on rails 2.3.x
Using .delay is what I'm doing now. Still, I'd like to simply use `handle_asynchronously` in my mailer model

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and eventually came across the following [post](http://groups.google.com/group/boston-rubygroup/browse_thread/thread/c9c49a1138723b95). Basically the delayed_job worker seems to have difficulties unmarshalling non-ActiveRecord objects. The quick fix which worked for me is to require your class in an initializer or environment.rb, e.g.

```
# config/environment.rb
...
require 'mail_sender'
```